# Missing library xfce

Tags: linux, xfce, crouton

I'm trying to execute GoPanda2 (an application to play Go that is supported for linux)

I'm on a chromebook acer720 running crouton. Following install instructions:
In a terminal window, extract the archive:

> tar xvf gopanda2-linux-64.tar.gz
>   Run the installation script
>   ./install.sh
>   Run the application by clicking on the icon or start it from the terminal

The issue I'm running into is:
"error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `libnss3` package. You have to install it along with its dependencies (in a apt linux system run `sudo apt-get install libnss3`, or `sudo yum install libnss3` in  a redhat based linux, and so on).

If there are still errors, please provide more informations.